# Printing multiple pages in Silverlight (4.0)?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing

I'm trying to print a grid that would comprise multiple pages from Silverlight 4.

The grid consists of a 'header section' (another grid with date, image, etc) setup as I needed it to look and a ItemsControl with a data template who's item source is set to an observable collection of objects.

All I set in the code so far is PageVisual (to the grid) but all I get is the first page.  So I believe I have to set HasMorePages (since the default is False).

But to do this, is it true I need to calculate the # pages in my code based on the # objects in my observable collection?  Such as by looping through the collection and creating uielement for each on a new stackpanel or the like?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Also is there a way to use the 'header section' I already created? I tried looping through the collection as mentioned above, but if I try and add the header grid to the a new stackpanel it says it is already child of a another element.  I don't want to have to create the header in c# code since it is already layout in xaml.  Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

Silverlight Business Apps: Module 6.2 - Multi Page Printing

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/SL4BusinessModule6/SL4LOB_06_02_MultipagePrinting/